# .net core 3.1 - General Questions/Design questions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

First, let me start by saying that I am in no way a professional coder, and as I've been in a different field for a number of years, I'm just now getting back into coding for a side project I have.  My old projects per ado.net (ms sql with stored procedures), web forms, with very little mvc/etc.

In the past, I would create classes like this:

```
public class blah
{
    public int Id;
    //more properties

    public static Get(id){ //call db class here, get row, use linq to convert to object }
}
```

Now, with .net core, that is considered "bad".  I'm learning EF, and hile I can use DI..I just find it messy to have chains of DI.  ie:  I can't just create an instance of the class using a default constructor..I have to now pass in the DI.  In order to do that, I need to chain up the DI to the controller, and w/e sub classes may need to use the specified class.  By default, in my startup.cs I have the required piece of code:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Now, in my classes, i can't just call ApplicationDbContext()...because it has to use the DI to get the connection string.  So I chain it up so the class looks like this now:

```
public class blah
{
    public int Id;
    //more properties
    private ApplicationDbContext _context;
    public blah(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
         _context = dbContext;
    }

    public static Get(id){ //use EF here to get the object }
}
```

This causes another issue, that now I can't do "blah myBlah = blah();" if I just want to create an instance of the class.  W/e I call it from, again has to have the DI.

Am I missing something there?  I've read ServiceLocators/etc are bad (antipattern) and should be avoided.
Note, I'm not just using "Controllers", but also trying to figure out where Razor pages/whatnot would fit in.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: No, you are not really missing anything - it might feel awkward and excessive at first, but once you get the hang of it there are many benefits - the bigger your project gets the more benefits you have. If it's just a spare time project you might never reach that point, but the concepts enforced here usually also lead to more clean code. Dependency Injection really comes to play when you work with automatic tests.

Comment: I'm not in the mood to write a huge answer, so I'll just leave a small hint:
You don't necessarily need to pass a service from the constructor to your method (especially if it is only used in a single method), you can also do `public void Get(int id, [FromServices] ApplicationDbContext dbContext)`.

Comment: Thank you Compufreak, I'll just get use to it I guess :D

Comment: You really need to read and investigate about Dependency injection if you want to be proficient in Asp.Net Core, using [FromServices], while can be useful at times, it is consider more clean to use only constructor injection.
You need to differentiate between a class that is a service, and a class that is a model.

Comment: So its more common now to separate the model and the "service" they provide?  It is easy enough.  Just have to shift what I am use to.  Current "tests" I am running separate out the model, the "view" of it that is being returned, the "service", and then this all gets called by a controller.  Hoping to convert it to a razor page though.  Is what I just described the most common way to do it nowadays?

Comment: it's a framework that's designed a certain way. Best to work within the framework if you decide to use it. Microsoft's "MVC" is just a brand name for a framework... and I think it causes confusion because they've sort of hi-jacked some words which used to describe an architecture.  Now your templates (.cshml files) = view... while half your .cs files = controller and half = model.  But the words mean something different than they would if talking about the architecture... for the most part you don't need to deal with the services...(the meat of the "controller" in the architecture context)

Answer (score 1):

Making it difficult or impossible to arbitrarily create objects is a side-effect of DI, and a good one. A module of code that does this is extremely difficult to test because its dependencies are implicitly contained within that code. Conversely, a module that explicitly specifies its dependencies up-front is easy to test, because you can mock or stub those dependencies to do the most minimal thing possible, to ensure that all you are testing is **that module**.

Forcing you to make your dependencies explicit forces you to think about how your code is designed. That leads to better-designed code.

Finally, on a more pragmatic note, if you're using a DI framework, why aren't you relying on it to do what it exists to do - create and inject your dependencies? Why are you trying to work around it?

As for service locators, perhaps you want to re-read the things you claim to have read. I think you'll find they state that using service locators **explicitly** is generally an anti-pattern - but ASP.NET Core DI is implicit.

Comment: Well as I said, I'm getting back into coding for a side project, and MVC/Razor Pages/DI/.net core/EF are all pretty new to me.  Mostly just wondering what the "correct" design is SUPPOSED to be :D